# Using git-flow, how to work rebase into the mix

Tags: git, github

I'm brand-new to rebasing.  I'm used to the [git-flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) method, whereby I branch off our main/develop branch, do my work, open a pull request on github, and it's merged in and we move on.  Works well.

Others are doing rebasing however, and I'd like to try it out.  I've read up on it ([here](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/) for instance) and while I get the idea, one bit confuses me.

In git-flow, when I make my changes to my branch, I push that branch to the server and open a pull request.  In a rebase, per the link above, I'm told to `Periodically rebase your feature branch onto the current state of the destination branch`..

...and if I do that, what do I then push to github?  The branch I've based onto, (`develop` in my case)?  As a git-flow guy that feels weird to me but maybe that's because I'm not used to it.

If there are other ideas on how to mentally shift from git-flow to doing rebasing I'm glad to hear of it as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Say your feature branch looks like this

```
* -- * -- A (master)
           \
            * -- * -- * (feature)
```

After some time, others have done work on `master` so that the history becomes

```
* -- * -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E (master)
           \
            * -- * -- * (feature)
```

The only thing that rebasing `feature` on to `master` does is to change when it appears you created the `feature` branch:

```
* -- * -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E (master)
                               \
                                * -- * -- * (feature)
```

By doing this periodically, you resolve any potential merge conflicts before they can pile up. If you merge master into feature periodically, you end up with lots of spurious merge commits in `feature`. With rebase, you avoid them, with the price being that you lose sight of when you initially branched `feature` from `master`. Keep in mind that you should only rebase if you *haven't* already pushed `feature`; once you do, you have shared the history of `feature` with others and should not change it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...if I follow correctly, 'rebasing `feature` onto `master`' actually means adjusting the feature branch, and not the master one-- that's where I was having confusion.

Comment: Right. If `feature` was "based" on A, rebasing to `master` makes it "based" on `master`.

Comment: For gitflow, usually a feature is worked on by one developer, so it is ok to rebase and force push the history to origin.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/rebase?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 6):

To periodically rebase your feature branch onto the current state of the destination branch (I'm assuming origin/master in this scenario), just do this from your feature branch:

```
git fetch origin            # Updates origin/master
git rebase origin/master    # Rebases current branch onto origin/master
```

An equivalent alternative:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

By doing so, you will keep your feature branch up to date with your origin/master branch. You can either merge it into your local master and push into origin/master  *or* you can just push your rebased feature branch to the remote repository and just do a pull request. It really depends on your git workflow.

Comment: Thank you for that.  One question however, and it's probably my ignorance speaking here--  If I rebase onto the master branch, why would I push my feature branch?  Is that not the same as what I'm doing in git-flow, with the extra (superfluous?) step of rebasing onto master?

Comment: Rebasing only changes the history of your feature branch; it does not make it visible from `master`. You still need to push it for others to see; it will just appear to them that you branched at a later point in time than you actually did.

Comment: In my solution, you are rebasing master onto your feature branch. At this point, your local master has no idea of your new commits, but your feature branch knows all the master commits and your newly added commits. If your workflow involves pushing your branch and using pull requests, this is a good way to do it.